# Redirect Android Microphone sound via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, android

I have been using the following command (answer by user *confetti* to a question on [redirect sound (microphone) via ssh, how to telephone via ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116919/redirect-sound-microphone-via-ssh-how-to-telephone-via-ssh/481851#481851?newreg=d8eabb8d47154da2bf227fa292f7e055)) to ssh to another laptop on the other end of the house to listen in to prayer services held during lockdown while working!

> ssh @ "arecord -f S16_LE -r 36000" | aplay

The laptop I'm connecting to however has a loud fan sound that comes through so I wanted to rather ssh into an android phone which has a better microphone as well as no fan sound. In addition the laptop is old and gets heated and shuts down often!

I installed an ssh server onto the android device and can ssh into it.  However when I use the command

> ssh admin@ -p 2222 "arecord -f S16_LE -r 36000" | aplay

I get the error:

> bash: arecord: command not found

> aplay: playback:2787: read error

Any advice/solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Install the `alsa-utils` package

Comment: Also What does the `aplay -l` shows?

Comment: aplay -l gives the following: 
>**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: I82801AAICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

doubt it's the alsa-utils as it does play when I ssh into a Linux Mint laptop.  Problem is when I ssh into Android...

Comment: Solution, just ended up using Mumble!